Spring getting validation error with pattern dd-MM-yyyy
I have a LocalDate field of an entiry class as below.
@DateTimeFormat (pattern="dd-MM-YYYY")
private LocalDate myDate;

I have a Date object when printed displays Thu Jul 07 00:00:00 IST 2022 and converted into LocatDate as below.
LocalDate myLocalDate = LocalDate.ofInstant(myDateObj.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));

which gets stored in DB as 2022-07-07
While displying this field on the page it is shown as 07-07-2022 as expected. But from webpage when I try to edit and save it with same format as 07-07-2022, I get the validation error as below.
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'myDate'; Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDate] for value [07-07-2022]


What makes you think that your database can store the date in a format of your choice? Which database engine are you using? I’m sure that it stores data type date in an internal format that we shouldn’t care about. Format your date for presentation, not for storage.

Ensure the pattern in @DateTimeFormat is "dd-MM-yyyy" instead of "dd-MM-YYYY".
The error you're encountering is likely due to a mismatch between the date format specified in your @DateTimeFormat annotation and the default date format used by Spring when parsing the date from the form submission. Update the Annotation like this:
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
private LocalDate myDate;


yyyy represents the calendar year.
YYYY represents the week-based year, which can cause parsing issues.

Regarding database Storage Format:
When you save a LocalDate to a database, it is stored in the database's default date format, which is often YYYY-MM-DD for SQL databases.
The formatting specified by @DateTimeFormat does not influence how dates are stored in the database; it only affects how dates are parsed from strings or formatted into strings during data binding.
Reference:
Refer to the DateTimeFormat Documentation for more information on spring's DateTimeFormat annotation. DateTimeFormat follows the original SimpleDateFormat style for date patterns.
